# tf.group_by_reducer example with list in the reducer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code which sums up values of each key. I am trying to use the list in the reducer since my actual use case is to sample values of each key. I get the error I show below? How do I achieve with a list(or tuple). I always get my data in the form of tensors and need to use tensorflow to achieve the reduction.

Raw data

```
ids | features
--------------
1   | 1
2   | 2.2
3   | 7
1   | 3.0
2   | 2
3   | 3
```

Desired data

```
ids | features
--------------
1   | 4
2   | 4.2
3   | 10
```

Tensorflow code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# this is a toy example. My inputs are always passed as tensors. 
ids = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
features = tf.constant([1, 2.2, 7, 3.0, 2, 3])

# Define reducer
# Reducer requires 3 functions - init_func, reduce_func, finalize_func. 
# init_func - to define initial value
# reducer_func - operation to perform on values with same key
# finalize_func - value to return in the end.
def init_func(_):
    return []

def reduce_func(state, value):
    # I actually want to sample 2 values from list but for simplicity here I return sum
    return state + value['features']

def finalize_func(state):
    return np.sum(state)

reducer = tf.contrib.data.Reducer(init_func, reduce_func, finalize_func)

# Group by reducer
# Group the data by id
def key_f(row):
    return tf.to_int64(row['ids'])

t = tf.contrib.data.group_by_reducer(
        key_func = key_f,
        reducer = reducer)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'ids':ids, 'features' : features})
ds = ds.apply(t)
ds = ds.batch(6)

iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
data = iterator.get_next()
print(data)
```

Following is the error I get

```
/home/lyft/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.pyc in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, defun_kwargs)
   2122     self._function = tf_data_structured_function_wrapper
   2123     if add_to_graph:
-> 2124       self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
   2125     else:
   2126       # Use the private method that will execute
AttributeError: '_OverloadedFunction' object has no attribute 'add_to_graph'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to group by in ids and get sum.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':[1,2,3,1,2,3], 'features':[1,2.2,7,3.0,2,3]})
>>> df
   features  ids
0       1.0    1
1       2.2    2
2       7.0    3
3       3.0    1
4       2.0    2
5       3.0    3
>>> df.groupby('ids')['features'].sum()
ids
1     4.0
2     4.2
3    10.0
```

Comment: Thats a toy example. My inputs are passed as tensors and cant use pandas. Need to use tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

You have set the initial value in `init_func` to `[]`. Then in `reduce_func`, you are trying to add a numeric value to `[]`.

Basically, you are trying to perform `[] + 1` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes:

```
def init_func(_):
    return 0.0
```

and

```
import numpy as np
```