# Keras custom loss function per tensor group

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pandas-groupby, loss-function

I am writing a custom loss function that requires calculating ratios of predicted values per group. As a **simplified** example, here is what my Data and model code looks like:

```
def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["feature_1", "feature_2", "condition_1", "condition_2", "label"],
                      data=[[5, 10, "a", "1", 0],
                            [30, 20, "a", "1", 1],
                            [50, 40, "a", "1", 0],
                            [15, 20, "a", "2", 0],
                            [25, 30, "b", "2", 1],
                            [35, 40, "b", "1", 0],
                            [10, 80, "b", "1", 1]])
    features = ["feature_1", "feature_2"]
    conds_and_label = ["condition_1", "condition_2", "label"]
    X = df[features]
    Y = df[conds_and_label]
    model = my_model(input_shape=len(features))
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, batch_size=128)
    model.evaluate(X, Y)


def custom_loss(conditions, y_pred):  # this is what I need help with
    conds = ["condition_1", "condition_2"]
    conditions["label_pred"] = y_pred
    g = conditions.groupby(by=conds,
                           as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x["label_pred"].sum() /
                                                           len(x)).reset_index(name="pred_ratio")
    # true_ratios will be a constant, external DataFrame. Simplified example here:
    true_ratios = pd.DataFrame(columns=["condition_1", "condition_2", "true_ratio"],
                               data=[["a", "1", 0.1],
                                     ["a", "2", 0.2],
                                     ["b", "1", 0.8],
                                     ["b", "2", 0.9]])
    merged = pd.merge(g, true_ratios, on=conds)
    merged["diff"] = merged["pred_ratio"] - merged["true_ratio"]
    return K.mean(K.abs(merged["diff"]))


def joint_loss(conds_and_label, y_pred):
    y_true = conds_and_label[:, 2]
    conditions = tf.gather(conds_and_label, [0, 1], axis=1)
    loss_1 = standard_loss(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)  # not shown
    loss_2 = custom_loss(conditions=conditions, y_pred=y_pred)
    return 0.5 * loss_1 + 0.5 * loss_2


def my_model(input_shape=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="relu"), input_shape=(input_shape,))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.compile(loss=joint_loss, optimizer="Adam",
                  metrics=[joint_loss, custom_loss, "accuracy"])
    return model
```

What I need help with is the `custom_loss` function. As you can see, it is currently written as if the inputs are Pandas DataFrames. However, the inputs will be Keras Tensors (with tensorflow backend), so I am trying to figure out **how to convert the current code in `custom_loss` to use Keras/TF backend functions**. For example, I searched online and couldn't find out a way to do a groupby in Keras/TF to get the ratios I need...

Some context/explanation that might be helpful to you:

1. My main loss function is `joint_loss`, which consists of `standard_loss` (not shown) and `custom_loss`. But I only need help converting `custom_loss`.
2. What `custom_loss` does is:

   1. Groupby on two condition columns (these two columns represent the groups of the data).
   2. Get the ratio of predicted 1s to total number of batch samples per each group.
   3. Compare the "pred_ratio" to a set of "true_ratio" and get the difference.
   4. Calculate mean absolute error from the differences.

Comment: What versions of Keras (standalone? tf.keras?) and Tensorflow are you using and are you ok with implementing this in Eager mode?

Comment: is the number of all possible condition values constant and known ahead of time ?

Comment: @runDOSrun I'm using a mix of keras.backend and tensorflow (2.2.0). Funny you mention Eager mode, because the solution I ended up coming up with only works in Eager mode and I'm not sure why! I just posted it so feel free to take a look.

Comment: @MohamedEzz yes the number of possible condition values is known ahead of time and constant (at least during the model run).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a solution to this, though I would like some feedback on it (specifically some parts). Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_array_ops


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["feature_1", "feature_2", "condition_1", "condition_2", "label"],
                      data=[[5, 10, "a", "1", 0],
                            [30, 20, "a", "1", 1],
                            [50, 40, "a", "1", 0],
                            [15, 20, "a", "2", 0],
                            [25, 30, "b", "2", 1],
                            [35, 40, "b", "1", 0],
                            [10, 80, "b", "1", 1]])
    df = pd.concat([df] * 500)  # making data artificially larger
    true_ratios = pd.DataFrame(columns=["condition_1", "condition_2", "true_ratio"],
                               data=[["a", "1", 0.1],
                                     ["a", "2", 0.2],
                                     ["b", "1", 0.8],
                                     ["b", "2", 0.9]])
    features = ["feature_1", "feature_2"]
    conditions = ["condition_1", "condition_2"]
    conds_ratios_label = conditions + ["true_ratio", "label"]
    df = pd.merge(df, true_ratios, on=conditions, how="left")
    X = df[features]
    Y = df[conds_ratios_label]
    # need to convert strings to ints because tensors can't mix strings with floats/ints
    mapping_1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    mapping_2 = {"1": 1, "2": 2}
    Y.replace({"condition_1": mapping_1}, inplace=True)
    Y.replace({"condition_2": mapping_2}, inplace=True)
    X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
    Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y)
    model = my_model(input_shape=len(features))
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
    print()
    print(model.evaluate(X, Y))


def custom_loss(conditions, true_ratios, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.sigmoid((y_pred - 0.5) * 1000)
    uniques, idx, count = gen_array_ops.unique_with_counts_v2(conditions, [0])
    num_unique = tf.size(count)
    sums = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(data=y_pred, segment_ids=idx, num_segments=num_unique)
    lengths = tf.cast(count, tf.float32)
    pred_ratios = tf.divide(sums, lengths)
    mean_pred_ratios = tf.math.reduce_mean(pred_ratios)
    mean_true_ratios = tf.math.reduce_mean(true_ratios)
    diff = mean_pred_ratios - mean_true_ratios
    return K.mean(K.abs(diff))


def standard_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)


def joint_loss(conds_ratios_label, y_pred):
    y_true = conds_ratios_label[:, 3]
    true_ratios = conds_ratios_label[:, 2]
    conditions = tf.gather(conds_ratios_label, [0, 1], axis=1)
    loss_1 = standard_loss(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
    loss_2 = custom_loss(conditions=conditions, true_ratios=true_ratios, y_pred=y_pred)
    return 0.5 * loss_1 + 0.5 * loss_2


def my_model(input_shape=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dropout(0, input_shape=(input_shape,)))
    model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.compile(loss=joint_loss, optimizer="Adam",
                  metrics=[joint_loss, "accuracy"],  # had to remove custom_loss because it takes 3 args now
                  run_eagerly=True)
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main updates are to `custom_loss`. I removed creating the true_ratios DataFrame from `custom_loss` and instead appended it to my `Y` in main. Now `custom_loss` takes 3 arguments, one of which is the `true_ratios` tensor. I had to use `gen_array_ops.unique_with_counts_v2` and `unsorted_segment_sum` to get sums per group of conditions. And then I got the lengths of each group in order to create `pred_ratios` (calculated ratios per group based on `y_pred`). Finally I get the mean predicted ratios and mean true ratios, and take the absolute difference to get my custom loss.

Some things of note:

1. Because the last layer of my model is a sigmoid, my y_pred values are probabilities between 0 and 1. So I needed to convert them to 0s and 1s in order to calculate the ratios I need in my custom loss. At first I tried using `tf.round`, but I realized that is not differentiable. So instead I replaced it with `y_pred = tf.sigmoid((y_pred - 0.5) * 1000)` inside of `custom_loss`. This essentially takes all the `y_pred` values to 0 and 1, but in a differentiable way. It seems like a bit of a "hack" though, so please let me know if you have any feedback on this.
2. I noticed that my model only works if I use `run_eagerly=True` in `model.compile()`. Otherwise I get this error: "ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 2 for ...". I'm not sure why this is the case, but the error originates from the line where I use `tf.unsorted_segment_sum`.
3. `unique_with_counts_v2` does not actually exist in tensorflow API yet, but it exists in the source code. I needed this to be able to group by multiple conditions (not just a single one).

Feel free to comment if you have any feedback on this, in general, or in response to the bullets above.